# heroku infinite loop for "cd frontend && npm run build" when pushing

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, heroku

so basically whenever I try to push to Heroku, or I try to run `npm run build` it would goes into infinite loop like this:

```
> projectname@1.0.0 build
> cd frontend && npm run build
```

in the terminal, i have a react app which has a package.json (let's call it inner package), and a package.json in the project folder level (let's call it outer package),

inner package code:

```js
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "node": "16.x"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

outer package.json:

```js
{
  "name": "cise_ass1a_worksheet3",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": "16.x"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "cd frontend && npm run build",
    "install-app": "cd frontend && npm install",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm run install-app && npm run build",
    "app": "nodemon app.js",
    "develop": "concurrently --kill-others-on-fail \"npm run app\" \"npm run start --prefix client\"",
    "start": "concurrently --kill-others-on-fail \"npm run app\" \"npm run start --prefix client\""


  },
  "author": "Ghazi",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.0",
    "config": "^3.3.7",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "mongoose": "^6.5.1",
    "validation": "^0.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.19"
  }
}
```

Comment: Ca you provide heroku logs? `heroku logs -t`

Comment: it just shows `> projectname@1.0.0 build
> cd frontend && npm run build` when i try to log.